# CCTMXTiledMap propertiesForGID:(CGPoint)

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

i m working in cocos2d 0.99.0

my project have a file with name CCTMXTiledMap.h & .m

but there is no public method with name propertiesForGID:(CGPoint)

so please if u have this method in your cocos2d

then please send me code of this method which i can use in .h and .m file.

thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That method was added in cocos2d 0.99.2.

You can download here:

https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/zipball/release-0.99.2

and get the files you need.  Probably would be best to update your cocos2d version though.

Comment: I double that. Cocos2D 0.99 was released exactly 2 years ago: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/blob/develop/CHANGELOG

Comment: You probably mean you second that ^^

Answer (score 2):

I think you should download the code from Ray Wenderlich [tutorial](http://www.hollance.com/2012/02/dont-abuse-the-app-delegate/) and replace the source cocos2d files within your project so it would be done completely.